# PermissionDenied, Unauthorized AccessException when i try to CP (copy a file)

Tags: windows, powershell, file-permissions, permission-denied, bitlocker

i have a hard drive that i use Bitlocker and was my main drive, but i sold the computer and bought a new one, then i got a case to use this SSD as an external drive.

Almost everything was ok, but there is one specific folder that i cant't access, see or move the Files.

Already tried to Take ownership of the files,to go to security tab and set all permissions for my user and for everyone. Tried with administrator powershell to copy and still nothing, even with -force, all i got is this.

When i use:

cp .\07.jpg c:

Then:

```
cp : O acesso ao caminho 'E:\Users\andre\Pictures\Dell WebCam Central\pics\07.jpg' foi negado.
```

In line:1 character:1

- cp .\07.jpg c:
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (E:\Users\andre\...ral\pics\07.jpg:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], Unauthorized
  AccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
  ```

Comment: Is the drive still encrypted with bitlocker?

Comment: I'm wondering, were these files created by Dell's webcam software?  I don't know how the software works, but I'm wondering does it load as a service, and then as a service, what account is it working as?  It is highly unlikely that this is the situation, but just wondering if a file is created by software running under the System account on a BitLocker drive, could it create this situation?  Worst yet, if so, how do you fix that?  Execute the copy command under the system account?